# Submitted blocks get rejected on Litecoin testnet

Tags: bitcoin-core, litecoin, block

I'm trying to submit blocks to the Litecoin Testnet, however everything gets rejected.

I got my raw value as
`000000026af779be9f0cdadfa71cc8fff6b0dac590fc3cc511f78523c40100a16147d5f478f8bdae4d3f1a8f58a0872248c98794b525ce18dd7d2ce6a905db27a368794e5329d0c31d502b23007b9f7e`

which hashed and reversed becomes
`000000026ccd88a7df4a643e7fb4a27301a36f750e94d6cb4c9dce5736f35783`

Should be enough to work on testnet. Diff checks out fine.
Since there are no transactions at the moment, I get `0 transactions` in my merkle tree, which should result in a `00` as the amount of transactions, and a total of `5000000000` satoshi as output value.

Now, when I add
`raw + count + outvalue` and submit, I get "rejected".

On [BIP_0022](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0022), which gives an overview of the error messages, it says `rejected: a generic rejection without details`. That doesn't help me.

Can somebody tell me what I am missing?